# jQuery webcam add-on that works on iOS Safari?

Tags: jquery, ios

Is there a jQuery webcam solution similar to this:

http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

that works on iOS Safari?

Comment: No, iOS doesn't run Flash, and a web-based solution requires Flash for camera access to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but the next release of iOS allows photos to be taken immediately when clicking an `<input type="file" />` button. This still won't allow for live webcam behavior, but allowing immediate upload of images is a step in the right direction

Comment: Wow, that's great news! Thanks! There should be another criteria though, as the website might actually be expecting another type of file aside from image.